# Expression denoting exclusivity

Tags: expressions, idioms, phrase-requests

Can anyone think of an idiomatic expression in English to show how exclusive something is? What I'm looking for is an expression that will instantly communicate to a native English speaker that only the super-rich will be able to access this thing (whether it be a product, a club, a location, etc.).

Comment: Les club au truffle? *We* don't go there. It's a **snooty** joint.

Comment: For a product, there's "if you have to ask, you can't afford it."

Comment: How about, "it's only for the 0.XX percent"?

Answer (score 1):

***Elite*** never goes out of style. Many of the suggestions above are less informative and more judgmental - "pompous"? I can be rich without being pompous. Others are simply poor word choices "nouveau riche" means new money and is used to imply flashy tackiness ("ballers"), the nouveau riche aren't invited into the traditional bastions of the elite. "Uber-chic" refers to style, which is continuously changing.  I'm not going to go through the entire list, and I'm not trying to offend anyone, I'm just trying to answer the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The term *uber-chic* may convey some of what you seek. *[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Uber-chic)* defines it as

> A word to describe something which is modern yet classy and elegant. Especially in interior design. *This table is so uber-chic!*

However, in usage, it often describes items or experiences that are the province of the ultra-rich. *[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/uber-chic)* lists numerous examples, including the following

> - They own 10 different hotel brands from the *uber-chic* Conrad Hotels to the family-focused Hampton Inns.
> - In California, where menu ingredients can have longer histories than college application essays, Mayor Gavin Newsom is also trying to take the fizz out of Pepsi, Coke, and even *uber-chic* artisanal-esque manufacturers like Jones Soda.
> - Now don't get me wrong, I can hold my own in a fashion crowd, it is my business after all, but let's face it, I'm an All-American girl who loves sports and may be considered the furthest thing from "*uber-chic* fashion muse".
> - You'll remember from last season that the *uber-chic* AMEX Skybox offers select VIPs and cardmembers an aerial view of the action inside the tents with commentary by fashion industry notables which this season include Harper's Bazaar editor AnaMaria Wilson, Bergdorf Goodman's Linda Fargo and designers Thakoon, Tory Burch and Philip Crangi.
> - What Cadillac needs to do today is embark on a branding campaign that can achieve for its luxury sedans what it has done for its Escalade, which has become the *uber-chic* vehicle for rappers, playboys, rich businessmen and limo fleets.
> - But obviously the Gateses didn't go to all the trouble and expense of launching a multimedia experience that debuts tonight at 7 p.m. at Washington's *uber-chic* Harman Center For The Arts (with simultaneous Webcast) simply to thank lil 'ol' taxpayin 'me.
> - Vivienne Tam was next on the itinerary with a presentation shown at her boutique in the uber-chic Jean Nouvel designed 40 Mercer building in Soho.
> - She was the -- flashing those gems for a spread in the *uber-chic* high-fashion magazine "Elle."
>
> [*emphasis added; original sources listed in the link*]

Answer (score 0):

How about any of the following:

> - clique, or cliquish
> - clan, or clannish
> - snobby
> - pompous
> - pretentious
> - highfalutin
> - society's crème de la crème
> - upper crust
> - aristocracy, aristocratic
> - a monarchic (or monarchical) group
> - high society
> - *haut monde* or *grand monde*
> - *coterie*
> - *nouveau riche*